# What's a good graphical SFTP utility for OS X?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, software-recommendation, ssh, ftp

I need a small graphical utility, using which I can ssh to a server and see all the files and copy and paste (drag and drop) into my local machine.

I am running Snow Leopard.

Comment: Just a note since you mentioned you're new to Mac (I'm basically the opposite): Using copy/paste to work with files seems to be a very PC thing. Drag and drop, like you mentioned, is the "Mac way," and you can use modifier keys to force a drag and drop to a duplicate/copy (option), move (command) or make alias (command+option). The default behavior changes based on if you are moving between two different volumes, and is always shown as a badge next to your cursor during the drag.

Comment: In the title you say FTP, in the question you say SSH. I think you're looking for is an SFTP utility (FTP over SSH). Like many have answered, Cyberduck is a great free and open source tool for this.

Comment: Since you're on Snow Leopard, have a look at [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) - you can just mount an ssh/sftp connection like a network volume, simple. *(note: it's may work with Lion too, [see here](http://groups.google.com/group/macfuse/browse_thread/thread/f5d3442e19cfed14))*

Comment: You can drag and drop in Windows. You can cut/copy/paste on a Mac. Both options work on both platforms. Which you choose to do is purely a personal preference.

Comment: You van use Finder for read only sftp acces. Go->Connect to server: sftp://123.123.123.123

Comment: 10 years on I would look at this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25666/237 rather than the accepted one. These 3 sftp clients are still going - seveal in tha accepted are not. Also the macFuse based ones are now in effect commercial.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

## [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) (Free)

A great free FTP client. This is my go-to application. Anytime I need FTP access, I use Cyberduck. It's not quite as lightweight as Fugu, but it adds a lot more functionality than Fugu. I also really like the Growl integration with Cyberduck.

[image: Cyberduck]

## [Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/) (Free)

Awesome little FTP client. As I noted above, this is a lightweight FTP client. It is great for simple FTP transfers and browsing. I do like the dual panel navigation.

[image: Fugu]

EDIT: I forgot to add these.

## [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) (Free)

I haven't actually used Filezilla extensively, but from what I've seen of it, I really like it. I downloaded it and played with it for a bit and I really like the tabbed connections. I also like the ability to jump to a path easily.

[image: Filezilla]

## [RBrowser](http://www.rbrowser.com/) (Free, $29 Upgrade)

A free FTP/FTP-SSL client. I don't usually use RBrowser because a $29 upgrade is necessary to unlock other protocols (Local, FTP/SSL/TLS, SFTP-SSH). I do like the Site Manager. It's a handy little thing to have.

[image: RBrowser Site Manager]
[image: RBrowser Browser]

I searched and came up with some other free FTP clients:

## [FireFTP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/) (Free) - Firefox extension

The one downside I see is that this is for Firefox. The website doesn't make it clear how it works with Firefox, so I assume it is an extension.

## [Macfusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) (Free)

This one relies on [Google's MacFUSE.](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) Since I don't know anything about MacFUSE, I don't know if this is good or bad.

## [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) ($34) By Panic

I have never used Transmit before, but I have used Coda and I definitely would recommend anything from Panic. The only reason I haven't used this because of the $34 price tag.

[image: Transmit by Panic]

## [ForkLift2](http://www.binarynights.com/) ($30)

Never used it, just found it when searching.

## [Fetch](http://fetchsoftworks.com/) ($24 per user)

An amazing program with a long, long, long mac heritage. It's way up there with Transmit by Panic and Interarchy as a file transfer program loved by long time Mac power users.

## [Flow](http://fivedetails.com/flow/) ($30)

Never used it, but looks good from the screenshots. I really like the fact that it looks like Finder. I may have to give this one a try.

[image: Flow]

## [OneButton FTP](http://onebutton.org/) (Free)

Just searching around and found yet another one...It looks pretty nice, except it's no longer supported. However, you can still download it.

[image: OneButton FTP]

Comment: Flow is an utter failure. Hasn't been updated since August 2010, and has long had a history of being quite flakey. I used earlier builds and suffered more than enough crashers to stop using it. The one window pane is quite counterproductive too. At it's current price point, it can't even compete with Transmit and Forklift.

Comment: Re MacFuse/MacFusion, it's good, but currently not working with OS X Lion. (this will also apply to [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html))

Comment: Transmit is well worth every bit of that thirty-four bucks. I'm also very selective about app purchases, and this is one that I can't do without. Definitely try it out — it's great.

Comment: +1 for Filezilla. I have used it on Win, OSX, and Linux for years.

Comment: Totally regret ever paying for Flow. They removed SFTP (or anything but regular FTP) support since their 1.4 update about 6 months ago, and AFAIK still haven't gotten around to supporting it again. Also, when contacting the developer about how terrible an idea that was, he basically flipped me (paying customer) the finger and said I had to be patient or move along. Now a more than happy Transmit user...

Comment: Please make this answer community wiki.

Comment: According to the [blog](http://blog.fivedetails.com) Flow is no longer in active development as its dev has joined Facebook.

Comment: Note that Cyberduck needs a Java runtime environment.

Comment: I like Filezilla. But there is one thing you should be aware of: passwords are stored in plain text in a configuration file. So anyone with access to your computer can easily read all your passwords stored within Filezilla. This is the main reason I am going with a different ftp-client now. Heres (one of) the thread(s) about this issue http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/5530 .

Comment: Cyberduck is 145mb!!! Really? For a simple ftp client? :-/

Comment: The FileZilla installer from SourceForge now includes some spyware/adware. I encourage people to stay away from any solutions that use/rely on Sourceforge. A better link for FireFTP is probably https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/ which gives more context about how FireFox extentions work.

Comment: FYI FileZilla can also handle pure SSH transfers, this is cool if you have to move files as lot on servers.

Comment: Cyberduck is nice, and I've used it for a long time, but it's really slow and RAM-hungry under heavy load. Probably because it's Java.

Comment: @sudo this is true. Also, this post was written 6 years ago. It's gotten considerably worse in that time.

Comment: Cyberduck no longer appears to be free (but it is still "libre"/open-source).  It's now about $24 on the App Store.

Comment: Fugu is power-PC only (it's kinda old at this point) and current versions of Mac OS X (eg: Sierra) do not support power-pc anymore, so it will not install.

Comment: @SeanColombo From [possible-duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39818/is-there-a-free-graphical-ssh-file-transfer-client-for-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1): there's a pre-release Intel version of Fugu available: [1.2.1.pre1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fugussh/files/Unstable/fugu-1.2.1pre1/Fugu-1.2.1pre1.zip/download)--with 2011 promise for a stable release coming soon.

Comment: looks like FileZilla was removed from Homebrew, per malware:  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/55583

Answer (score 52):

### Transmit

[image]

Panic's [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) tops my list. An extremely well built and executed FTP Client that fully supports sFTP. Priced at **$34.**

> Transmit is an excellent FTP (file transfer protocol), SFTP, S3
>   (Amazon.com file hosting) and iDisk/WebDAV client that allows you to
>   upload, download, and delete files over the internet. With the most
>   Mac-like interface available, Transmit makes FTP as simple, fun, and
>   easy as it can possibly be.

### Forklift

[image]

[Forklift 2](http://www.binarynights.com/) is another terrific client that is just as solid and just as well built. Priced at **$29.95**.

> ForkLift will connect to any remote server FTP, SFTP, Amazon S3,
>   WebDAV, the SMB, NIS and AFP shares on your local network, or your
>   Bluetooth mobile phone- pretty much anything you can plug into or hook
>   up to a Mac. ForkLift also carries a complete toolbox for managing
>   your files, including Folder Synchronization, Batch Renaming, Archive
>   handling, Application deleter, editing files over remote connections
>   and many more. All these power features are packaged into a
>   Finder-like, dual-pane interface that delivers superior workflow while
>   remaining absolutely familiar to use, along with QuickLook, Spotlight
>   search and all.

### Cyberduck

[image]

Lastly, [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) rounds out the list. It is not as well polished, but it sturdy and does the job. It is free.

> Cyberduck is a robust FTP/FTP-TLS/SFTP browser for the Mac whose lack
>   of visual clutter and cleverly intuitive features make it easy to use.
>   Support for external editors and system technologies such as
>   Spotlight, Bonjour, Keychain and AppleScript are built-in.

There are others to be sure, but these are the one's I've used and personally recommend. Additionally, you may want to hit up places like [MacUpdate](http://www.macupdate.com), [VersionTracker](http://www.versiontracker.com/macosx), or [iUseThis](http://osx.iusethis.com/) for these types of questions. You will find much more diversity and get a better understanding of the programs available to you.

Comment: I used Cyberduck for many years (couldn't see paying for an FTP client), then tried to use it to transfer several hundred files at once. It completely choked. Transmit handled the job with ease.

Comment: Transmit is definitely the Rolls-Royce of FTP Utils. I use it even when I'm not ftping for quick chmod's, browsing hidden directories, etc. It's almost perfect.

Comment: For-pay apps, Transmit is the de-facto-standard on OSX for FTP/SFTP. Do it. It's like a magical rainbow filled with unicorns, with a big pot of gold at the end.

Comment: Transmit, $34 you will not regret.

Comment: Cyberduck is 145mb!!! For s simple ftp client. Are they nuts? What did they use to write it? Javascript?

Comment: +1 for FileZilla. It does the work as expected, no issues. Free.

Comment: Which on supports ssh tunneling?

Comment: +1 for Filezilla. After that sourceforge debacle, they started self-hosting (as did other popular apps). I came here as a Windows user trying to see what others use on a Mac.

Answer (score 7):

## [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com)

[image: ExpanDrive]

ExpanDrive acts just like a USB drive plugged into your computer. Open, edit, and save files to remote computers from within your favorite programs—even when they are on a server half a world away. ExpanDrive enhances every single application on your computer by transparently connecting it to remote data.

Comment: This is a nicely done app for sure and I will probably be buying it. However, it seems that it does not perform some operations efficiently. I am on a slow network connecting to a foreign SFTP host. If I copy the contents of one foreign folder to another, it should just issue a copy command on the server. However it seems that it copies all data to my local computer, and then back up. It should be a very quick operation (1 or 2 seconds) but it is taking minutes instead.

Comment: ExpanDrive mounts local volumes, not remote volumes. If you access an ExpanDrive mounted FTP volume from Path Finder, expect the owner/group to be those of your local machine and not those of your remote server.

Comment: @GabeJohnson I wonder how many clients actually do that. The two remote machines may not even be able to reach each other in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

### [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)

[image]

I have tried Cyberduck and Flow in the past but Filezilla offers a side-by-side interface which is quite useful. The only limitation with this tool is that it's not really MacOSX-aware, e.g. it shows all hidden files

Comment: The FileZilla installer from SourceForge now includes some spyware/adware. I encourage people to stay away from any solutions that use/rely on Sourceforge.

Answer (score 2):

Most other answers gave an objective analysis, but I'll share my experience.

Top clients:

- Flow: really nice interface.
- Transmit: very fast, can mount as Finder volume.
- Cyberduck: the best for the inexistent buck.

Answer (score 1):

Add to others

Unfortunately RBrowser in not compatible with BigSur onwards

## [RBrowser](http://www.rbrowser.com/)

This provides more of an interface like Finder than the others (stricyly much more like the original NeXT version) Apart form standard ssh/ftp it will syncronise directories etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A more recent option is to use the newer implementation of [Fuse for OSX](https://osxfuse.github.io/) in combination with [SSHFS](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS). This is a better solution because most of the applications mentioned are either outdated or payed (and expensive).

Fuse for OSX allows you to use new file systems in user space and SSHFS configures the system to allow you to connect to SSH drives automatically, as if they were drives supported by OSX.

Comment: I wouldn't count a command line solution as a _graphical SFTP utility_.

Comment: "...as if they were drives supported by OSX." means you can see and use the remote machine in Finder. In MacPorts there is also a simple gui for mounting a remote machine, so you don't need the command line at all. This solution works perfectly with the ssh agent for password less logins too.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). It has support for browsing a remote computer via SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

Yummy FTP (commercial) : http://www.yummysoftware.com/

Can't believe the one that blows most of the above out of the water hasn't yet been mentioned.

Comment: This website has been repurposed.  I read that: "Yummy FTP is no longer being supported and sold by Yummy Software after its developer passed away."

Answer (score 0):

If you need graphical utility with support for SSH you may try [CRAX](https://web.archive.org/web/20141008082353/http://crax.soft4u2.com/). This software has a built-in SSH client and after connection to the SSH server it's possible to invoke file operations like copy, move, and delete.

[image: CRAX Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the answers on this. Be sure to read the [promotion section](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) on [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) if you recommend the same software several times.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth considering some of the Web-based alternatives, like [Monsta FTP](https://www.monstaftp.com) (Disclaimer: I'm involved with this).

They save you having to install software on every device; instead you do it all through your Web-browser, with the same features as any desktop client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with large files, then maybe consider [Truck.app](http://bonhardcomputing.com/truck/).
It employs rsync for file transfers, which is generally faster than FTP.

[image]

Disclosure: I am the developer of Truck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Cyberduck and Transmit. None of them has functionality of preserving modification date. SCP on terminal does that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up ssh public key authentication, you can use

[SSHFS-Mountlet](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/applications/SSHFS-Mountlet/) [image: icon of SSHFS-Mountlet]

which is a graphical front end to sshfs. It provides a menu bar icon under which you can mount or unmount your connection you have set up before. Sshfs has already been suggested by Fernando in a previous answer. Handling of the remote files happens using the macOS Finder.

I was unhappy with the GUI clients for sshfs, so I wrote my own (GPL'ed).

Answer (score -1):

CaptainFTP is the best choice

Easy to download from itunes:

http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/captain-ftp/id416544161?mt=12