# Is there a (free) graphical SSH file transfer client for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, ssh, utilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a good graphical SFTP utility for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25661/whats-a-good-graphical-sftp-utility-for-os-x)

I'm looking for an SSH client that includes drag and drop file transfer functionality. I'm aware of CyberDuck, but it's a bit pricey. I found one or two other programs, and they're not free. I need it for my computer science class this semester. (I'm technically ok using the Terminal, but some of my Mac using classmates are not.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/client_features.php) can also do full SFTP (FTP over SSH) and it's free.

The downside obviously is it's not a very pretty application under OSX.

Comment: Ah, I knew about that one too, didn't know it did SFTP.

Comment: I would have also added Fugu, but its 10.6 and below only.

Comment: I was able to use FileZilla on Win 10 to connect to a Ubuntu machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, I was wrong. [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) is donation ware, so it will serve my purposes over the semester.

Comment: Just to expand on that slightly - Cyberduck is open source, released under [GPLv3](https://cyberduck.io/license/). The developer does ask for donations but they are not required to use the software.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel guilty about not donating to Cyberduck even though you've found it useful, [Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/) is the daddy of SFTP clients for OS X... completely free and open source. The stable versions are PPC only, but there's a [pre-release Intel version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fugussh/files/Unstable/fugu-1.2.1pre1/) available.